# Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (5749,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am a beginner in Deep Learning and was building a program that determines the person from its image. But my neural network is showing an error and I have no idea on how to fix it -

```
model.fit(imgs_array,Y,batch_size = 401, epochs = 2, validation_split = 0.2)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1527, in fit
    x, y, sample_weights = self._standardize_user_data(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 991, in _standardize_user_data
    x, y, sample_weights = self._standardize_weights(x, y, sample_weight,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1149, in _standardize_weights
    y = training_utils.standardize_input_data(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 329, in standardize_input_data
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (5749,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

My complete code is

```
import os
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.python import keras
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, Dropout


folders = os.listdir('lfw/')
# print(len(folders))       #5749
folders_a = np.asarray(folders)

image_files = []
X = []
Y = []
for folder in folders:
    files = os.listdir('lfw/'+folder+'/')       # type of files is a list
    image_files.append(files)
    for file in files:
        X.append(file)
        Y.append(folder)

# print(len(Y))     #13233
img_paths = []
for i in range(0,13233):
    img_paths.append('lfw/'+Y[i]+'/'+X[i])      #img_paths is set now

print(len(img_paths))

imgs = []
for img_path in img_paths:
    img_1 = load_img(img_path, color_mode="grayscale")
    imgs.append(img_to_array(img_1))

    # print(imgs[0].shape)      #(250,250,1)



Y = np.array(Y)
# print(type(Y))
# print(Y.shape)        #(13233,)

#Building Neural Network
imgs_array = np.array(imgs)
imgs_array /= 255


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(20, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', input_shape =(250,250,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(20, kernel_size =3, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(401, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(5749,activation = 'softmax'))
print("compiling initiated")
model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error',optimizer = 'sgd')
print("model compiled")
model.fit(imgs_array,Y,batch_size = 401, epochs = 2, validation_split = 0.2)
```

What is the cause of the error and how to fix it? The `print(Y.shape)` line in the code above gives me output `(13233,)` . Why does it show `(1, )` in the error?

Note - I have seen the links given below but they do not address my question.

[Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (257, 257) but got array with shape (257, 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50858871/error-when-checking-target-expected-dense-1-to-have-shape-257-257-but-got-ar)

[Error in fitting an RNN LSTM model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848107/error-in-fitting-an-rnn-lstm-model/50851822#50851822)

[Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (256,)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661239/error-when-checking-target-expected-dense-1-to-have-shape-1-but-got-array-wi)

Answer (score 0):

From a quick glance, I think your problem is the following:
your network takes tensors of shape (batch_size, 250, 250, 1) as input
and gives tensors of shape (batch_size, 5749) as output

When you start fitting, keras takes batches of input data and corresponding labels, so it feeds your network input tensors of shape (batch_size,) + imgs_array.shape[1:]
and labels of shape (batch_size,) + Y.shape[1:]

That is for every image in the batch, your label is a scalar (or apparently a one dimensional vector, I didn't read that thoroughly) and your output with which you are comparing it is a tensor of size 5749, which is not a scalar.